# Use .htaccess to remove a directory and .php extension from the URL

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I am running a Wordpress website, but I have some folders not related to the wordpress CMS, but in the same directory where all Wordpress folders are.

The .htaccess in root WP folder has its standard script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Everything what is related to Wordpress CMS is working perfectly. Now I have that other folder named `companies`, inside that folder there is a lot of other sub-directories with the company names. There will be more folders created every day, so the current URL for this problem is:

```
www.example.com/companies/company-name/employee.php
```

and my goal for this is to have

```
www.example.com/company-name/employee
```

(also removing the `.php` extension).

How to achieve this?

I have tried modifying `.htaccess` in the root folder, the best result was that I could get my desired link to work, but then the whole WordPress site and all images would not be loaded.

Should I create a new `.htaccess` inside `companies` folder? I would not mind creating a new `.htaccess` file every time in new the folder (I am that desperate to get this working).

Comment: "I have tried modifying .htaccess in the root folder" - Please include what you have tried. Do you have other resources (JS, CSS, images) inside `/companies`? Or do you _only_ have URLs of the form `/company-name/employee` that should reference this filesystem path?

Comment: There is CSS file and few images inside /companies.The CSS and images are for the PHP files inside /company-name folder

Comment: Addition to that comment, I could get rid of any files in /companies folder and place them somehwere else, if that would help to reach the solution to the problem easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I create a new .htaccess inside "companies" folder?

No. In order to hide the `/companies` directory from the URL you are going to have to modify the `.htaccess` file in the parent directory. ie. the WordPress `.htaccess` file in the document root.

> There is CSS file and few images inside /companies

So I assume you intend to remove `/companies` from all URLs - not just the "employee" URL mentioned.

In order to avoid conflicts with WordPress, you first need to test whether the resource being requested exists in the `/companies` directory. If so, rewrite the request. Otherwise, let the request fall through to WordPress.

Try something like the following, *before* the existing WordPress directives, in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews

# Any requests for /companies directly are ignored
# This includes rewritten requests (below)
RewriteRule ^companies/ - [L]

# Check if the requested resource exists in the /companies subdirectory.
# If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/companies/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif))$ /companies/$1 [L]

# Check if the requested PHP file exists in the /companies subdirectory
# if requesting a URL that does not already have a file extension.
# NB: Assumes the URL-path does not otherwise contain dots.
# If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory appending ".php"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/companies/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /companies/$1.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# :
```

Note, that this doesn't actually *remove* the `/companies` subdirectory (or `.php` extension) from the URL (as suggested in the modified question title) - for that you need to modify the actual links to these files in your HTML source.

This allows you to access the pages/resources without having to specify the `/companies` directory in the URL.

> **UPDATE:** Is it possible to do redirection from this original one to the new one?

Yes, modify the first rule:

> ```
> # Any requests for /companies directly are ignored
> # This includes rewritten requests (below)
> RewriteRule ^companies/ - [L]
> ```

To the following instead:

```
# Redirect any "direct" requests to the `/companies` directory
# to remove the directory from the URL-path.
# Also removes the ".php" extension (if present)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^companies(/.*?)(?:\.php)?$ $1 [R=302,L]
```

The regex capturing subpattern `(/.*?)` is non-greedy (denoted by the `?`), this is to avoid capturing the *optional* `.php` file extension.

The condition (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` *environment variable* ensures that we only check direct requests and not rewritten requests by the directives below. This avoids a redirect loop. The `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var is not set on the initial request and is set to the HTTP status code (ie. `200`) after the first successful rewrite.

This redirect is only really required if the old URLs have already been indexed by search engines and/or linked to by external 3rd parties. This does not avoid having to replace the old URLs in the application.

Note also, that this is currently a temporary (302) redirect. Only change this to a permanent (301) redirect once you have confirmed it works OK.

### Summary

Bringing to the two parts together:

```
Options -MultiViews

# Redirect any "direct" requests to the `/companies` directory
# to remove the directory from the URL-path.
# Also removes the ".php" extension (if present)
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^companies(/.*?)(?:\.php)?$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Check if the requested resource exists in the /companies subdirectory.
# If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/companies/$1 -f
RewriteRule (.+\.(css|js|png|jpg|gif))$ /companies/$1 [L]

# Check if the requested PHP file exists in the /companies subdirectory
# if requesting a URL that does not already have a file extension.
# NB: Assumes the URL-path does not otherwise contain dots.
# If so, rewrite the request to that subdirectory appending ".php"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/companies/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /companies/$1.php [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# :
```

Comment: Incredible! More importantly, with all comments... Now I can access the required URL from the original link (www.example.com/companies/company-name/employee.php) and the new one (www.example.com/company-name/employee). Is it possible to do redirection from this original one to the new one?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to redirect the "old" URLs if required. I've updated my answer.